# Composition of a smoothing operator with an $L^2$-bounded operator, non-compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, pseudo-differential-operators, micro-local-analysis, integral-kernel

I'm trying to close in on a definitive answer to my own question [BVPs for elliptic PDOs: When do Green functions ($L^2$ inverses) define pseudo-differential operators in the interior?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285548/bvps-for-elliptic-pdos-when-do-green-functions-l2-inverses-define-pseudo-d), and think I have reduced it to the following subproblem about the interplay between smoothing operators and (bounded) $L^2$ operators preserving smoothness (see below) on a Riemannian manifold.

**Setup/notation:** Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, *not necessarily compact or complete*, and let $\mathrm{d} \mu_g$ be the smooth measure on $M$ determined by the volume density of $g$. Let $L^2(M,\mathrm{d} \mu_g)$ be the resulting Hilbert space of functions on $M$ which are square-integrable with respect to $\mathrm{d} \mu_g$. Let $G : L^2(M,\mathrm{d} \mu_g) \to L^2(M,\mathrm{d} \mu_g)$ be a bounded linear operator with the property that $G[C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)] \subseteq C^\infty(M)$—if necessary for the proof, I'm happy to also assume that $G[H^{s}_\mathrm{c}(M)] \subseteq H^{s+k}_\mathrm{loc}(M)$ for all real $s \geq 0$ and some fixed $k > 0$, where $H^{s}_\mathrm{c}(M)$ and $H^{t}_\mathrm{loc}(M)$ are the standard spaces of compactly supported Sobolev distributions and of locally Sobolev distributions on $M$, respectively. In the latter case, however, I am *not* willing to assume from the outset that the resulting maps $H^{s}_\mathrm{c}(M) \to H^{s+k}_\mathrm{loc}(M)$ are continuous in the standard topologies of these Sobolev spaces. Let also $\mathscr{D}'(M)$ denote the standard space of distributions on $M$, and $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ the space of distributions with compact support. A *smoothing operator* is a continuous operator $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M) \to \mathscr{D}'(M)$ whose Schwartz kernel is an element of $C^\infty(M \times M)$.

**Question:**  If $R$ is a *properly supported* smoothing operator [so that $R$ sends $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ to $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$], does it follow that the composition $GR$ defines a smoothing operator?

**My understanding:**

1. By my assumption on $G$, $GR$ is well-defined as a linear map from $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ to $C^\infty(M)$. This is a purely algebraic statement.
2. An immediate analytic prerequisite is that the related linear map $\widetilde{GR} : C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M) \to \mathscr{D}'(M)$, given by postcomposing with the obvious embedding, should be continuous when $\mathscr{D}'(M)$ has the standard weak topology. But this is the case because properly supported operators are continuous from $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$ to $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$, while $L^2$-bounded ones such as $G$ define continuous maps from $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$ to $\mathscr{D}'(M)$.
3. As far as I know, even when taken together the statements in 1. and 2. do not automatically ensure that we are dealing with a smoothing operator proper. According to [this note](http://math.mit.edu/~eyjaffe/Short%20Notes/Distribution%20Theory/On%20Smoothing%20Operators.pdf), we **also** need to know that $GR:\mathscr{E}'(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ is sequentially continuous when $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ has the weak topology and $C^\infty(M)$ has the standard Fréchet space topology. Alternatively, there is the following characterization of smoothing operators which I am adapting from Dieudonné's *Treatise on Analysis*, Vol. 7, (23.11.1) (and see also a similar statement in Hörmander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I*, Theorem 5.2.6):

   > Let $K$ be a linear map from $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ to the Fréchet space $C^\infty(M)$ which is continuous on all bounded subsets of $\mathscr{E}'(M)$. Then $K$ is the extension to $\mathscr{E}'(M)$ of a smoothing integral operator.

Under my minimal assumptions on $G$ I am not sure how to establish that either of the continuity conditions in 3. is satisfied.

Comment: This is the connection with my original MO question: there, $G$ is a Green function for an elliptic differential operator $P$. $P$ admits a pair of properly supported pseudo-differential operators $Q, R$, with $R$ smoothing, such that $PQ = I + R$. Then, when both sides are restricted to $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$, we can left-compose with $G$ to get $G = Q - GR$, and in order to establish the pseudo-differential property of $G$ it suffices to establish that $GR$ is a smoothing operator.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled, because the note that you reference gives this equivalent criterion for being smoothing: that we have such an extension $GR: \mathcal{E}^\prime(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$. But its proof also requires the hypothesis that $M$ be a closed manifold, hence both compact and complete! I don't have access to Dieudonne's text, but you should check whether he requires this condition as well.

Comment: Since everything here is local, I doubt that the assumption of compactness is really needed.

Comment: Is this right: Since $GR$ is a bounded operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$, it has a kernel. Since it maps all distributions to smooth functions, the kernel has to be smooth?

Comment: But could you explain why you need such a general result? The operator $G$ is pseudodifferential operator of finite order, so $GR$ is a smoothing operator.

Comment: The note explicitly states that the extension has to have the sequential continuity property that I mention in the text. It also claims (though without proof) that the result holds regardless of compactness assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for attacking the problem, Deane. I didn't assume that $G$ is pseudodifferential in either this question or the one this links to. Indeed, it is precisely what needs proving in the other question.

Comment: Ostensibly, the equivalence criteria in Yaffe's note (linked in the question) or in Dieudonné seem to suggest that some strong form of continuity has to be satisfied in addition to the existence of a kernel and to the mapping property from distributions to smooth functions.

Comment: I think the crux of the issue (if you agree with what I've said so far) is that we have no initial knowledge of the continuity properties of the restriction of $G$ to a map $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$. The only continuity assumed is in the $L^2$ sense both in the domain and codomain.

Comment: Yes, I see that now! The issue of compactness covered by your replacing $\mathcal{D}^\prime(M)$ with $\mathcal{E}^\prime(M)$ according to this remark 0.2

Comment: Incidentally, similar comments go for Dieudonné's version. Since I asked the question, I found that essentially the same criterion as Dieudonné's can be found in Hörmander's _The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I_, Theorem 5.2.6.

Comment: Don't we have a continuous inclusion $L^2\hookrightarrow \mathscr D'$? Then $G$ is a continuous map $L^2 \to \mathscr D'$ so that its restriction $C_c^\infty \to C^\infty$ has closed graph and is thus continuous (where $C_c^\infty$ is endowed with its inductive limit topology).

Comment: Thanks Jochen. But I thought we had to check continuity into $C^\infty$ with the Fréchet space topology (uniform convergence of all derivatives on all compact sets), and not with the relative topology as a subset of $\mathscr{D}'$. Isn't there something more to check then?

Comment: The closed graph theorem applies to linear maps from LF-spaces to Frechet spaces and continuity with respect to coarser Hausdorff topologies implies closed graph.

Comment: Ah! I think this _does_ answer the question! Would you like to write that up as an answer, or shall I?

Comment: I will not have time to write a detailed answer. Fell free to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I have now done so (here and in the other question which motivated this one), and hope I have not misunderstood the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jochen Wengenroth's [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287167/composition-of-a-smoothing-operator-with-an-l2-bounded-operator-non-compact/287375#comment710638_287167), I can now give the full answer: the idea is that $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M) \hookrightarrow L^2(M, \mathrm{d} \mu_g) \xrightarrow{G} L^2(M, \mathrm{d} \mu_g) \hookrightarrow \mathscr{D}'(M)$ is continuous, and an argument using a version of the closed graph theorem in the (locally) Fréchet category then shows that simply by virtue of mapping $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$ to $C^\infty(M)$, $G$ must actually do so *continuously* with respect to the Fréchet topology of $C^\infty(M)$. In detail:

**Lemma.** Let $T:C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M) \to \mathscr{D}'(M)$ be linear, continuous relative to the standard inductive limit topology of $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$ and the weak topology of $\mathscr{D}'(M)$, and with image contained in $C^\infty(M)$. Then $T:C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ is continuous relative to the standard Fréchet space topology of the codomain.

*Proof.* $T$ is continuous as a map $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ when the codomain is equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathscr{D}'(M)$. Hence its graph is closed in the appropriate product topology, and it is also closed in the finer product topology obtained by equipping $C^\infty(M)$ with its Fréchet space topology. The result then follows from the fact that the closed graph theorem is applicable to linear maps from LF-spaces to Fréchet spaces.

**Wrapping up.** Since $R : \mathscr{E}'(M) \to C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(M)$ is continuous, so is the composition $GR : \mathscr{E}'(M) \to C^\infty(M)$. By the equivalence criteria I mentioned in the question, this implies the smoothing property.

Thanks to all who helped with this.